# Android ImageView not stretching vertically in ListView row

Tags: android

I have been struggling with this for several days now and I ran out of ideas.

In my listview, each row can have a vertical bar flushed left with a different color depending on status. That "bar" has no other purpose than visual representation of status and is not clickable.

I implemented the vertical bar using an ImageView with background set to a drawable which has the desired color. The problem is that the vertical bar doesn't stretch, it's only 1 pixel high even though I specified fill_parent.

The row layout is like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/d1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/id1">
...
```

(leaving content of the second relative layout out on purpose for simplicity)

My drawable d1 looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/c1" />
    <corners android:topRightRadius="5dip" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip" />
</shape>
```

So,

1. Why isn't the ImageView stretching vertically?
2. Is there a better way to implement
   this than using an ImageView? (I
   tried a simple View with a
   background color but it doesn't show
   up at all)

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you may as well be using a horizontal LinearLayout here instead of a RelativeLayout (since you only have two children anyways, you're not really saving any layout complexity the way you're using it).

Changing to a LinearLayout may fix this, but I suspect you may be running into a specific issue when it comes to matching heights on inflated RelativeLayouts as rows; see the comments on the answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895303/androids-relativelayout-seems-broken) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499555/android-layout-centering-in-relativelayout-for-custom-listview).

Comment: I had a relative layout because there is actually a text view above the object that i omitted to keep the xml short for this post. I read the posts from the links you gave me and I am already using the correct way of inflating the view. However, I am going to try swapping the Relative layout with multiple LinearLayouts to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks Yoni for pointing me to those valuable SO threads. Replacing the root RelativeLayout with a LinearLayout fixed the problem. Not sure I am a big fan of this solution because that makes the layout hierarchy more complex than needed but that may be the only way to get it to work. A bug?